# Eclipse: script compiler as part of a project

Tags: eclipse, maven, yacc, lex

This question is not limited to lex and yacc, but how can I add a custom script compiler as part of a project? For example, I have the following files in the project:

```
grammar.y
grammar.l
test.script
```

The binary 'script_compiler' will be generated using grammar.y and grammar.l compiled by lex, yacc and g++. And then I want to use that generated script_compiler to compile test.script to generate CompiledScript.java. This file should be compiled along with the rest of the java files in the project. This setting is possible with XCode or make, but is it also possible with Eclipse alone? If not, how about together with Maven plugin?

(I might setup the script compiler as a separate project, but it would be nice if they can be put in the same project so that changes to the grammar files can be applied immediately)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom "Builder" from the project properties dialog.  This can be an ant script (with an optional target) or any other script or executable.

There are also maven plugins for [ant](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and other [scripting languages](http://mojo.codehaus.org/script-maven-plugin/languages.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nicholas. I'm not familiar with Ant but will try.

Comment: In that case, do yourself a favour and s/ant/maven/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run an external program in Maven this is what you want: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ -- you can then run Maven targets from your IDE or command line and it should do the right thing either way.

To integrate with the normal compilation bind the plugin to the "generate-sources" phase and add the location where the Java files are generated to the "sourceRoot" option of the exec plugin. That way the compiler will pick them up.

Ideally you generate the code into a folder "target/generated-sources/MY_SCRIPT_NAME". That is the standard location for generated sources in the Maven world and e.g. IntelliJ IDEA will pick up source files inside of that location. Note that this doesn't work if the files are directly in "target/generated-sources".

The other option is to write your own Maven plugin, which is actually quite easy as well. See e.g. https://github.com/peterbecker/maven-code-generator